# If $L=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end {bmatrix}$ and $E=\begin {bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end {bmatrix}$, then find $(aL+bE)^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am doing matrices on my own due to the quarantine, so please bear with me.

Doing the obvious would be to just solve all the multiplication and additions, and then cross checking with the given options, which I did. But I am sure that’s not the right way to do it. What method should be applied in this?

Answer is $a^3 L +3a^2bE$

Comment: As in, you actually formed the matrix $aL+bE$ and did the matrix multiplication?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I got close to it, but looking at the insane amount of calculation, I didn’t think it was the right way to go. I am confident that one can obtain the answer by matching the options, but i will try it again

Comment: Since $L$ and $E$ commute, examine powers of $E$ and then expand using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $E^2=0$, we have:

$$(aL+bE)^3=a^3L+b^3E+aLbEaL+aLaLbE+bEaLaL=a^3 L +3a^2bE$$

because every term $E^n$ with $n \geq 2$ is equal to $0$.

This type of matrix are known as "nilpotent" so we say that $E$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Oh, i didn’t think the standard polynomial laws applied to matrices, because I saw an example where $(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+AB+BA$

Comment: I read it again, but that is obviously not the standard equation. How did you get it?

Comment: Thanks to distributive property $(A+B)(C+D)=AC+AD+BC+BD$

Comment: @Aditya, $L$ and$E$ commute.

Comment: Yes I get it now.